# If a row does not exists insert else don't insert in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to check if a row exists or not. If it does not exist, it should be inserted.

This is in `postgres` and I am trying to insert row through a shell script. When I run the script it does not show error but it does not insert into table even though no matching row is present.

Comment: Please post the script you are using and the statement you are using to test if there is "no matching row".

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555966/merge-syntax-used-to-upsert-or-insert-on-duplicate-update

Comment: if you can use Ruby as your scripting language, you might try [`Upsert`](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert)

Comment: I'm *upset* (not to be confused with *upsert*) that many of you have disregarded the distinction between insert-if-not-exists (asked by this question) and upsert (asked by the erroneously-marked duplicate question).

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question; its answers aren't exactly applicable here. It may be a duplicate of [a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4069718/1068283).

Comment: This is absolutely not a duplicate of the linked question.  Please vote to re-open.

Answer (score 28):

I like the solution they mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql)

```
INSERT INTO table (id, field, field2)
       SELECT 3, 'C', 'Z'
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id=3);
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it is not working as have a lower version. Hence, I wanted to split both of them into two different queries.

Comment: Postgres also now has an Upsert command where you can insert OR update a row:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT

Comment: On 9.5+, `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` or `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE` https://stackoverflow.com/a/17267423/1386245

Comment: @Rohmer note: rohmer's solution only works if you have a constraint on the table